# Recommendation to communicate data between a python 3.6 script and a python 2.7 script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.6, transfer

I am running two python scripts. One using python 3.6 an other suing python 2.7. The script with python3.6 gathers data from a logitech G27 game controller. The script with python2.7 needs to get this data and publish it using ROS. Hence the need for two different scripts as ROS is compatible with python 2.7.

I have tried to make the Python 3.6 script work with python 2.7. But, there will be a lot of changes that will need to be made to the code. Even then I am not sure if it will work or not.

My expected behavior is that the python 3.6 script sends continupus stream of data which can then be acquired by python 2.7 script.

Comment: Python 2 and 3 both support memory-mapped files via the `mmap` modules (as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html#module-mmap) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html#module-mmap), so that might be an option.

Comment: I don't know what the scripts look like exactly, but given your information, you might be able to send your data to the python 2.7 script using os.system. I recommend you take a look at this article: https://linuxhandbook.com/execute-shell-command-python/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this python library : [Pyro](https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/)

As per its documentation, you can use "normal Python method calls to call objects on other machines". So you can call methods of python 2.7 with Python 3.6 or vice versa with this library.